# Evaluating a linear integral (Calculus I)

Tags: calculus

I'm given:
$$\int_{5}^{-2} [3f(x) + 1]\,dx$$

with the additional information that:
$$\int_{0}^{5} f(x)\,dx = 10$$

and 
$$\int_{0}^{-2} f(x)\,dx = -4$$

My layman mind looks at it as, since the sum of the two function pieces = 6, then the integral is $3(6) + 1 == 19$

Is that the right way of looking at the problem, or am I missing something?

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: +1 for explaining what you tried/what you were thinking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is nearly the right idea.

By [linearity of the integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearity_of_integration) we have $$\int_{-2}^5 (3f(x)+1)dx=3\int_{-2}^5 f(x)dx+\int_{-2}^5 1 dx=3\int_{-2}^5 f(x)dx+7.$$  Notice the $+7$ instead of the $+1$, because we are integrating the constant function $1$ on an interval of length $7$.  Also, it is true that $$\int_{-2}^5 f(x)dx  =\int_{0}^5 f(x)dx+\int_{-2}^0 f(x)dx$$ but we are not given $\int_{-2}^0 f(x)dx$, instead we have $\int_{0}^{-2} f(x)dx$.  How do these two integrals relate, and can you solve the problem from here?

Hope that helps,

Comment: So now, I'm getting an answer of $49$ i.e. $3(14)+7$. That look right?

Comment: @NateyG:  That definitely looks like the answer to me.  Nice work.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int_5^{-2}(3f(x)+1)\,dx = 3\int_{5}^{-2}f(x)\,dx + \int_5^{-2}1\,dx.$$

But:

1. $\int_5^{-2}1\,dx\neq 1$.
2. $\int_5^{-2}f(x)\,dx \neq \int_0^5f(x)\,dx + \int_0^{-2}f(x)\,dx$.

Instead, remember that

- $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx = -\int_b^a f(x)\,dx$;
- $\int_a^c f(x)\,dx = \int_a^b f(x)\,dx + \int_b^c f(x)\,dx$;
- $\int_a^b 1\,dx = b-a$.

Comment: Typo: limits of integration (5 to -2) on the 1st integral on the RHS.

Comment: @Américo: Thanks! Was away, so didn't see this.